# Design A List of Lists Sortable By Frequency of Occurence

Tags: java, design-patterns

### The Setup

I have a list of pairs of integers: ( (1,2), (1,3), (2,5), (1,6), (2,8), (9,8), (8,11) etc).  Within a given pair, the numbers must be different, but there are many repeats when you consider the list as a whole.

Though this information is not strictly relevant to the problem, each number represents a card from a deck (and is between 1 and 52 inclusive), and each pair represents one of a player's possible cards.

### The Problem

We want to sort these pairs of numbers such that pairs containing the most frequent cards across the list as a whole come first.  Those pairs are then ordered by the 2nd number, ascending. Then we repeat the process using the *remaining pairs* on the list.  Ties are broken using the rule that smaller numbers come first.  Let's do an example using the list from above:

1. The numbers 1, 8, and 2 each appear 3 times on the list, and no number appears more than 3 times.  Hence there is a 3 way tie, and 1 wins.  We construct the first portion of the list as follows:

   ```
   (1,2)
   (1,3)
   (1,6)
   ```
2. The remaining list items are now (2,5), (2,8), (9,8), (8,11).  8 appears 3 times, more than any other number, hence 8 wins.  We continue our list as follows:

   ```
   (1,2)
   (1,3)
   (1,6)
   (2,8) <-- Note 2 is the smallest of the "other" numbers amongst the 8 group
   (9,8)
   (8,11)
   (2,5) <-- This gets added in step 3, but since there is only 1 left we add it now
   ```

### Answer Criteria

Obviously I don't expect anyone to write the complete algorithm for me, but I would like input on how best to design it, perhaps with some small bits of pseudocode.  My goals are efficiency, readability, and simplicity, in that order.

Specifically:

- What Collections object should I use to represent both the pairs and the overall list?
- Should I get counts for each integer once at the beginning of the algorithm, and then update them by subtracting as they are used?  Or should I redo the counts after each pass?  The former seems more efficient.
- Within a phase, what is the best way to do the sorting by the "other" number in the pair?
- How about the sorting when ties occur?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: it looks like you're sorting starting Texas Hold'em holecards in a special way.  Can you elaborate a bit on what you're doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this qualifies as a design pattern.  You do need to think about your design, but it would need to be a very common problem to qualify as a pattern, which is not the case.

```
public class CardAndPairs implements Comparable<CardAndPairs> {
    Card card;
    List<Pair> pairs;

    public CardAndPairs(Card card, Set<Pair> allPairs) {
       this.card = card;
       pairs = new HashSet<>();
       for (Pair pair : allPairs) 
         if (pair.contains(card))
           pairs.add(pair);
       // You could then reorder "pairs" by the value of the other card
       // ... see below
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CardAndPairs other) {
       int diff = pairs.size() - other.pairs.size();
       if (diff > 0)
          return 1;
       if (diff == 0)
          return card.compareTo(other.card);
       return 1;
    }
}
```

You could then put the CardAndPairs for the 52 cards in a List and sort them automatically (implicitly using `compareTo`) with `Collections.sort(list)`.

To sort the pairs within a given `CardAndPairs` in the constructor above, it gets a bit convoluted to do it the Java way.   Instead of using just a straight `Pair`, you should define a subclass than implements Comparable:

```
public class PairWithGivenCard 
          extends Pair implements Comparable<PairWithGivenCard> {
   Card givenCard;
   Card otherCard;

   public PairWithGivenCard(Card givenCard, Pair pair) {
      this.givenCard = givenCard;
      for (Card card : pair) // or however you get the cards from pair
         if (card != givenCard)
            otherCard = card;
   }

   @Override
   public int compareTo(PairWithGivenCard otherPair) {
      // It might be a good idea to throw 
      //   some exception if givenCard != otherPair.givenCard
      return otherCard.compareTo(otherPair.otherCard);
   }
}
```

You would then need to change `List<Pair> pairs` by `List<PairWithGivenCard> pairs` in the constructor of `CardAndPairs`.  And when you add a pair to the list, you would have to do `pairs.add(new PairWithGivenCard(card, pair))` instead of `pairs.add(pair)`.  Finally you just call `Collections.sort(pairs)` at the end of constructor of `CardAndPairs`.

Comment: toto2, this was above and beyond, one of the most thorough answers i've ever gotten on so. thanks!